Sevlets with @WebServlet annotation in JAR files not accessible (wildfly 26.1.3.Final)
I have a project where I need to include some servlets. For some reasons the customer wants a JAR file not a WAR file. After a few days research I was unable to find a solution to make wildfly's servlet container load the servlets annotated with @WebServlet from JAR file (@WebServlets from WAR file are working great but we can't deploy WAR file).
Is there a way how to make the servlets working from jar file?
My server is WildFly 26.1.3.Final with servlets version 4.0
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(name = "hello", urlPatterns = {"/hello"})
public class Web extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        resp.getWriter().println("<html><head><title>hello</title></head><body>");
        resp.getWriter().println("<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
        resp.getWriter().println("</body></html>");
        resp.getWriter().close();
    }
}

I expected that the servlet container will start the web context and load the servlet with the annotation.

You should clarify your problem and add details. Why can't you deploy your application to WildFly server?

Roman, OP wants to launch a servlet based application as a JAR file. This of course won't work by attempting to "deploy" a JAR file to a managed servletcontainer the same way as a WAR file. OP is basically looking for something like Spring Boot. With that framework you can launch a servlet based web application with an embedded servletcontainer as a JAR file with java command. The embeddedable servletcontainer part of WildFly is available under the brand Undertow. This is also supported by Spring Boot. Now you can try doing the research for an answer :)

You can also use the wildfly-jar-maven-plugin to create a bootable JAR for WildFly.
